# how to make elements Aligned inside div

Tags: css

I have a div with few elements , my label and textbox inside a div are not well aligned , You can see the screenshot .. 
Any idea to align these legal name and business name and textbox , so all the textboxes should start from the same point

thanks

[image]

Comment: share your code please we will not going to copy that :-P

Comment: instead of showing screen shot create a demo jsfiddle showing your issue?

Comment: Use a table or use CSS right property from the div

Comment: `label { clear:left; float: left; width: 150px; /* modify as you prefer */ }` what about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `width` for your labels and inputs:

```
.the-label {
    width: 160px;
}

.the-input {
    width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Widths are fine, but never use inflexible units like px for text, since you're not guaranteed to have control over the font size (some users do change this in their browser).  Use ems instead.

Comment: This code does not prevent line breaking, does not set `height` and does not hide `overflow`, so I think it's ok for font-resizing. I've used `px` for the sample, but units will be what the layout demands (percents or pixels most of the times)

Comment: And what about labels that are only a single word?  `Password` does not wordwrap (though both labels the OP uses are 2 words).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/FmKfP/

Answer (score 0):

You could align them using an invisible table.

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Legal Name:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Business Name:</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's an awful solution from 80's. Don't use tables for building layout. Tables are for tabulating content.

Comment: No, tables are bad *if* they are used for layout instead of displaying tabular data.  I would argue that a collection of key/value pairs are just as appropriate in a table as a set of data that has 3 or more columns in it.  After all, if he had more than 1 record, it would have been arranged horizontally instead of vertically and no one would have batted an eye.

Comment: Hard-coding the maximum width of labels is IMHO even worse solution. Even when it is hard-coded in ems instead of pixels, because... what if you later want to translate the application to another language? The tables will scale. Show me a solution without tables *and without hardcoding*, and I will be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask yourself which is worse:  using a table or using enough mark-up that it looks like a table but with spans/divs instead of trs/tds.  I think tables are fine in this instance (if you've worked with relational databases, it's not uncommon to have lots of tables with only 2 columns), others will assure you that it is evil.

You can use a width on your label elements as already suggested or you can use slightly less evil CSS tables.

```
div.pseudo-row { display: table-row }
/* input might need to go in a container and have the container set to table-cell instead */
div.pseudo-row label, div.pseudo-row input { display: table-cell }

<div class="pseudo-row">
<label for="first-item">First item</label>
<input type="text" id="first-item" />
</div>

<div class="pseudo-row">
<label for="second-item">Second item</label>
<input type="text" id="second-item" />
</div>
```

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/

For the record, I would just use tables in this instance and save the CSS table display properties for another day.